# What are the default initialization options for Regex?

Tags: .net, regex, constructor

The .Net C# offers two (well four) constructors:

```
Regex(String) 
Regex(String,RegexOptions)
```

The first constructs a regular expression with default options, while the second gives you somewhat more control. Take a peak under the hood with Reflector shows that the first constructor calls the second with a RegexOptions.None as second parameter. MSDN documentation doesn't reveal much more.

What are the true default options when using the first constructor? is it compiled? is it case sensitive etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more information, look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Default

Answer (score 3):

It's equivalent to using RegexOptions.None - it's not compiled, it's case-sensitive, etc. (Basically look at RegexOptions, and it's the opposite of selecting them :)